# Upsampling with learned interpolation layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, interpolation

In [Wave-U-Net](https://github.com/f90/Wave-U-Net), they use learned_interpolation_layer for upsampling in decoder. They upsampled 2 times.

Their code for this layer is:

```py
def learned_interpolation_layer(input, padding, level):
    '''
    Implements a trainable upsampling layer by interpolation by a factor of two, from N samples to N*2 - 1.
    Interpolation of intermediate feature vectors v_1 and v_2 (of dimensionality F) is performed by
     w \cdot v_1 + (1-w) \cdot v_2, where \cdot is point-wise multiplication, and w an F-dimensional weight vector constrained to [0,1]
    :param input: Input features of shape [batch_size, 1, width, F]
    :param padding:
    :param level:
    :return:
    '''
    assert(padding == "valid" or padding == "same")
    features = input.get_shape().as_list()[3]

    # Construct 2FxF weight matrix, where F is the number of feature channels in the feature map.
    # Matrix is constrained, made up out of two diagonal FxF matrices with diagonal weights w and 1-w. w is constrained to be in [0,1] # mioid
    weights = tf.get_variable("interp_" + str(level), shape=[features], dtype=tf.float32)
    weights_scaled = tf.nn.sigmoid(weights) # Constrain weights to [0,1]
    counter_weights = 1.0 - weights_scaled # Mirrored weights for the features from the other time step
    conv_weights = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.diag(weights_scaled), axis=0), tf.expand_dims(tf.diag(counter_weights), axis=0)], axis=0), axis=0)
    intermediate_vals = tf.nn.conv2d(input, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding=padding.upper())

    intermediate_vals = tf.transpose(intermediate_vals, [2, 0, 1, 3])
    out = tf.transpose(input, [2, 0, 1, 3])
    num_entries = out.get_shape().as_list()[0]
    out = tf.concat([out, intermediate_vals], axis=0)
    indices = list()

    # Interleave interpolated features with original ones, starting with the first original one
    num_outputs = (2*num_entries - 1) if padding == "valid" else 2*num_entries
    for idx in range(num_outputs):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            indices.append(idx // 2)
        else:
            indices.append(num_entries + idx//2)
    out = tf.gather(out, indices)
    current_layer = tf.transpose(out, [1, 2, 0, 3])
    return current_layer
```

They have upasampled two times.There equation for upsampling is:

[upsampling equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awvRk.png)

But I require to upsample 4 times. So I tried this with this way by transforming the equation:
[four times upsampling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEWRi.png)

The upsampling providing output shape (4n-4,c), for the input (n,c). Where n is the feature length and c is channel.

The deep learning architecture I am working with is encoder decoder based architecture. In encoder portion convolution layer degrading input shape from (4n+4,c) to (n,c)(kernel_size=8, stride=4). So when I am using learnable upsampling layer expecting increasing input shape from (n,c) to (4n+4,c). But the approach I followed provide input shape from (n,c) to (4n-4). So for this compatibility issue causing the model is underfitting. I have tried to alleviate the problem through duplicating beggining and last value of input feature before the calculations of learnable upsampling layer. This degrades training loss significantly. But I am still not getting expected output.
My learnable upsampling layer implementation:

```
class learnable_upsample_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, padding="valid", level=0):
    super(learnable_upsample_layer, self).__init__()
    self.padding = padding
    self.level = level

def build(self, input_shape):
    features = input_shape[-1]
    self.w1 = self.add_weight(name="interp_{}_w1".format(self.level), shape=(features,), initializer='random_normal', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
    self.w2 = self.add_weight(name="interp_{}_w2".format(self.level), shape=(features,), initializer='random_normal', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
    self.w3 = self.add_weight(name="interp_{}_w3".format(self.level), shape=(features,), initializer='random_normal', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)


def call(self, inputs):
    assert self.padding in ["valid", "same"]
    first_value = inputs[:, 0:1, :]
    last_value = inputs[:, -1:, :]
    inputs = tf.concat([first_value, inputs, last_value], axis=1)
    print("Coming here")
   
    w1_scaled = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.w1) * 0.33
    w2_scaled = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.w2) * 0.33 + 0.33
    w3_scaled = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.w3) * 0.33 + 0.66
    c1_weights = 1.0 - w1_scaled
    c2_weights = 1.0 - w2_scaled
    c3_weights = 1.0 - w3_scaled
   
    conv_weights1 = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(c1_weights), axis=0), tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(w1_scaled), axis=0)], axis=0)
    conv_weights2 = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(c2_weights), axis=0), tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(w2_scaled), axis=0)], axis=0)
    conv_weights3 = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(c3_weights), axis=0), tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.diag(w3_scaled), axis=0)], axis=0)
   

    # conv_weights1 = tf.expand_dims(conv_weights1, axis=0)
    # conv_weights2 = tf.expand_dims(conv_weights2, axis=0)
    # conv_weights3 = tf.expand_dims(conv_weights3, axis=0)
   
    in_vals1 = tf.nn.conv1d(inputs, conv_weights1, stride= 1, padding=self.padding.upper())
    in_vals2 = tf.nn.conv1d(inputs, conv_weights2, stride= 1, padding=self.padding.upper())
    in_vals3 = tf.nn.conv1d(inputs, conv_weights3, stride=1, padding=self.padding.upper())

    in_vals1 = tf.transpose(in_vals1, [1, 0, 2])
    in_vals2 = tf.transpose(in_vals2, [1, 0, 2])
    in_vals3 = tf.transpose(in_vals3, [1, 0, 2])

    out = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])

    
    num_entries = inputs.shape[-2]
  
    out = tf.concat([out, in_vals1, in_vals2, in_vals3], axis=0)
    indices = []
    increase = num_entries - 1
    num_outputs = (num_entries + increase * 3)
 
    val_ind = 0

    for idx in range(num_outputs):
        indices.append(val_ind)

        if idx % 4 == 0:
            val_ind += num_entries
        else:
            val_ind += (num_entries - 1)

        if idx % 4 == 3:
            val_ind = int((idx + 1) / 4)
    
    out = tf.gather(out, indices, axis=0)
    output = tf.transpose(out, [1, 0, 2])

    output = output[:,:-1, :]
    print("Shapes ", inputs.shape,output.shape)
    return output
```

How should  learnable upsampling layer should implemented for given scenario?

Comment: Please add a **library/framework** tag.